# How to update data into MongoDB by matching data from a file using Spark Java

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark

I'm reading the data from MongoDB collection

```
String ipuri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1/mydb.data";
String opuri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1/mydb.data";

SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("InsertData")
                .set("spark.mongodb.input.uri", ipuri).set("spark.mongodb.output.uri", opuri)
                .set("spark.app.id", "InsertData")
                .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaMongoRDD<Document> mongodata = MongoSpark.load(jsc);
```

Next I'm also reading a json file

```
Dataset<Row> df = sqlContext.read().json("/home/praveen/report.json");
```

Now I would like to match the values from report.json & MongoDB. If it matches I must update data from json file into MongoDB.

If I add to list using foreach..I'm getting an empty list

```
List list= new ArrayList();
df.foreach(x-> {list.add(x);});
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: you can put the contents of `report.json` in a for loop and check if it matches the data from mongodb and based on that you can implement your function to update.

Comment: Can you give any snippet?